Добавление ключей в JSON
Проблема такова, с телеграм бота по нажатию кнопки вызывается код из writer.py.
После чего добавляется ключ "1" со своим значением text
(Грубо говоря то что ввёл пользователь).
Но при повторном выполнении он заменяет ключ "1" на ключ "2" с другим значением text.
А мне нужно чтоб он добавлял ключи до указаного числа в цикле for.
Файл writer.py:
import json
from db import db

def write(inf, text):
    a = db.db.name[f'{inf}']
    for i in range(1, 100000000000000):
        with open("../db/info.json", "r") as f:
            b = json.load(f)
        if f"{i}" in b[a]:
            print("Sucess")
            continue
        else:
            b[a] = {f"{i}" : f"{text}"}
            break
    with open("../db/info.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(b, file, indent=4)

Файл info.json:
{
    "antiparasitic": {},
    "cleansing the liver": {},
    "starvation": {},
    "body care": {},
    "training": {},
    "worldview": {}
}


вы же сами написали в коде b[a] = {f"{i}" : f"{text}"} - вот он вам и заменяет. из кода не понятно, что такое b, например. возможно, вам нужно сделать b[a][i]= f"{text}"}.

@strawdog, b это ключ из данных в info.json  по типу "worldview" или "antiparasitic"
